# token.botframework.com => An error occured while retrieving the signin link

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm building a MS Teams Messaging extension using botframework, following this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=node-js%2Cnode-js-dialog-sample#create-the-resource-group

and based on this example:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config

Everything goes well, up to the moment I click the "Sign-in" button on my "auth" card.

The link, generated by

```
const signInLink = await context.adapter.getSignInLink(
  context,
  this.connectionName
);
```

opens a popup, containing the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ServiceError",
    "message": "An error occured while retrieving the signin link"
  }
}
```

[image: token.botframework.com error]

I double and triple-checked everything - the resource groups, the Teams dev portal, the config of the IDP etc - everything seems to be correct.
Cannot find any logs or any information, that could allow me to continue.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just figured out, that it works as expected when deployed to the cloud. The issue is only reproducible when debugging locally.

Comment: Will check this issue at our end and will get back to you.

Comment: Hi @Teodor Todorov - Could you please confirm, have you provided your local ngrok URL  while registering your application?

Comment: Thanks, @Mamatha-MSFT!  I used the VSCode TeamsFX extension and the app was registered automatically. However the ngRok URL gets updated every time the application starts, so I do confirm it's set, if by this you refer to teams dev portal => Tools => Bot management => Bot name => Configure

Comment: @TeodorTodorov- could you please confirm if copying the signInLink generated to browser and see if login works fine?